# Cannot fetch parameter from remote node using RemoteGetParamReq

Tags: unetstack

I am developing an energy based routing protocol, where in I am trying to use `RemoteGetParamReq` from one node, to fetch residual energy of its neighbor node, but the request is returning `FAILURE` response.

I have exposed the energy(`init_energy`) as the parameter of `PHY` by defining `enum`, and also I have defined `getParameterList()` method to associate the `enum` in my modem class.

How to fetch energy parameter of remote node using `RemoteGetParamReq`

This is the code I am trying with

```
remote << new RemoteGetParamReq(to: 2, remoteAgentID:  phy).get(MyEnergyParameters.init_energy)
```

This is the enumeration defined;

```
import org.arl.unet.Parameter

@com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter(org.arl.unet.JsonTypeAdapter.class)
public enum MyEnergyParameters implements Parameter{
    init_energy
}
```

Comment: Can you query the parameter on the local node shell?